# Dynamically Creating list in Struts2 using tags

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, tags

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(2012);
list.add(2013);
list.add(2014);
list.add(2015);
```

can we do same as above using struts2 tags. may be by using

```
<s:set name="myList" value={somedynamic values} />
```

actually I want to create a list of number of 10 years on JSP page using Struts2 tags.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding to your question answer is yes,but `that is not an good idea to create number of 10 years` in jsp page.

However, this is using arrylist in dynamic way

```
<s:select label="Years" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Years" list="list"   name="your desire name" />
```

in the place of list property you have to give arrayList variable in your case it is `list`
means,

<`s:select ---- list="your array list variable" --------- />`

and you have to define this action name in `struts.xml` 
   eg:

```
<action name="yourarrylistvariable" class="your class" method="your method">
           <result name="success">your jsp page</result>
</action>
```

This is using arrylist in static way here you have to change the list value

```
<s:select label="Years" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Years" 
list="#{'2000':'2000', '2013':'2013',.....}" name="your desire name" />
```

For More Info You can refer this link [struts2 select](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, thanks to the OGNL you can create lists like so:

```
<s:set var="myList" value="{2012,2013,2014,2015}" />
```

See this [link](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl.html#OGNL-Collections%28Maps,Lists,Sets%29).